# How do I play another track automatically after the first is ended using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio, playback

I am trying to figure out how to play another track immediately after the first one has ended automatically and then the whole thing to loop again until the user presses pause.

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  isPlaying ? myAudio.pause() : myAudio.play();
};

myAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
 <audio id="myAudio" src="/sound/track.mp3" preload="auto" loop="true">
    </audio>
    <button id="play-pause"><a onClick="togglePlay()">PLAY/PAUSE SOUND</a></button>
```

Comment: use `audio.onended` event listener

Comment: Can you add a bit of clarification on how I would add this to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Firstable don't write inline JavaScript, it has a lot of disadvantages, and since you want to change the song when the current ends, you should get rid of the `loop` attribute cause you don't want to keep playing just one song, and you don't need to track the playing state of the audio element, it has already a property `audio.paused` to tell if it's playing or not, and I see no reason to add an `<a>` tag inside the button element, here is an example of playing some songs from a playlist it's all dynamic, feel free to add the number of songs you desire

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio"),
  // a simple playing list
  playingList = ["v1601656608/lambada_saxo_bxdmys", "v1601656600/coffin_dance_saxo_ze81hy", "v1601656611/mr_saxobeat_saxo_snh2di"],
  currentSong = 0;

// set the initial song url to be the first song in the playlist
myAudio.src = `https://res.cloudinary.com/dzcscgx8y/video/upload/${playingList[0]}.mp3`;

document.querySelector("#play-pause").onclick = function() {
  myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
}

myAudio.onended = function() {
  // change the src to be the url of the next song, if the song is the last one in the playlist then the next should be the first one
  this.src = `https://res.cloudinary.com/dzcscgx8y/video/upload/${playingList[++currentSong === playingList.length ? 0 : currentSong]}.mp3`;
  // the audio player stops after playing each song, so after changing the src just launch the player
  this.play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" src="" preload="auto"></audio>
<button id="play-pause">PLAY/PAUSE SOUND</button>
```